# `NewConnectionError` while using gevent pool

Tags: python, concurrency, gevent

While trying to use gevent to parallelize IO bound work, I'm getting a ton of these error messages:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='blabla.com', port=80): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /bla (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 16]
>   Device or resource busy'))

My code looks uses a utils such as this:

```
def run_parallel(f, it):
    return pool.Group().map(f, it)
```

What is the correct way to avoid these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was missing the monkey-patching part.

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```